# when matched update not working oracle merge

Tags: sql, oracle, insert-update, on-duplicate-key

Here is something interesting! The `merge` statement works fine. But when the values match, it does not update the status to 'B' as expected. Any idea why?

```
merge into bbbt b 
using (select bank,ifsc,branch,
              center,district,state,
              address,status 
         from rtgbrn_temp 
        where ifsc in (SELECT ifsc 
                         FROM rtgbrn_temp 
                        MINUS 
                       SELECT ifsc_code 
                         FROM bbbt)
        ) x
   on (x.ifsc = b.ifsc_code)
 when matched then 
   update 
      set rtgs_stat = 'B' 
    where (x.ifsc=b.ifsc_code)
 when not matched then 
   insert (bankid,benbrn_code,brn_name,
           brn_addr,brn_loc,brn_stat,
           brn_city,coun_code,
           remarks,ifsc_code,
           rtgs_stat)
   values (substr(x.ifsc,1,4), substr(x.ifsc,5), 
           x.branch, x.address, x.district, 
           x.state, x.center,'IN', x.bank, x.ifsc,'R');
```

[also tried using the on duplicate update, but failed to work with an error]

```
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended!

insert into bbbt(bankid,benbrn_code,brn_name,brn_addr,brn_loc,brn_stat,brn_city,coun_code,remarks,ifsc_code,rtgs_stat)
select substr(x.ifsc,1,4), substr(x.ifsc,5), x.branch, x.address, x.district, x.state, x.center,'IN', x.bank, x.ifsc,'R' from 
(select bank,ifsc,branch,center,district,state,address,status from rtgbrn_temp where ifsc in (SELECT ifsc FROM rtgbrn_temp MINUS SELECT ifsc_code FROM bbbt))x
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rtgs_stat = 'B';
```

please share your knowledge, thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `where` in the update part. Did you try without it?

Comment: yes, I did. But it didn't make a difference..

Comment: Check your data -- the code looks ok.

Comment: it is merging, but not updating to 'B' when matched.. still..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values from the query cannot match.

Look carefully at this part of the query.

```
select ..., ifsc, .....
from rtgbrn_temp 
where ifsc in (........
               .........
               MINUS 
               SELECT ifsc_code 
               FROM bbbt )
```

This query retrieves `ifsc` codes that **are not equal** to any `ifsc_code` in `bbbt` table.
Then the query uses these codes to match records:

```
 on (x.ifsc = b.ifsc_code)
```

the above is eqivalent to

```
on (subquery.ifsc = bbbt.ifsc_code)
```

because `x` is an alias of the subquery, and `b` is the `bbbt` table name.

Think a while .... 
The subquery returns only codes that are not equal to any value of `bbbt.ifsc_code`
It means, that the condition `subquery.ifsc = bbbt.ifsc_code`  **never matches**.

Comment: hey, you are absolutely right. thank you for enlightening really! i changed the code to the following after removing the duplicates so you wont get the error "SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"

Answer (score 0):

edited code:

```
merge into bbbt b using (select bank,ifsc,branch,center,district,state,address,status from rtgbrn_temp) x
on (x.ifsc = b.ifsc_code)
when matched then update set rtgs_stat = 'B'
when not matched then insert (bankid,benbrn_code,brn_name,brn_addr,brn_loc,brn_stat,brn_city,coun_code,remarks,ifsc_code,rtgs_stat)
values (substr(x.ifsc,1,4), substr(x.ifsc,5), x.branch, x.address, x.district, x.state, x.center,'IN', x.bank, x.ifsc,'R');
```